# trying to get the average calculation from these inputs

Tags: java, android

```
public class MyCalculator {

    int q  = 1;
    int w  = 2;
    int e  = 3;
    int r  = 4;
    int t  = 5;

    public float average() {
        // TO DO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
        int average = (q + w + e + r + t);
        average = average / 5;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I calculated the average from these inputs but I don't know why my answer is wrong, and here is my answer under the word `TO DO`. I tried to get the sum and then divided by their number.

Comment: why `return 0`? it should be `return average`

Comment: Next question will be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 0 and not the average that you calculated

Answer (score 0):

it will be and error because your function is expecting to return a float datatype,
thats why you need to change your average datatype to float,
then return average not 0